# Why doesn't intellisense work as expected on a new installation?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I installed vscode 1.8.1 on my Windows 7 system and I have the following issues:

1. Code not being highlighted:

   [image: http://i.imgur.com/TDrhh7i.png]
2. Intellisense not giving me autocomplete with built-in functions (e.g. `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty`)

I expected this to work out of the box considering JavaScript is supported by default. Additional question, is it possible to set the zoom percentage to a specific value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resetting to defaults by deleting the files under here worked:

```
%appdata%\Code\Local Storage
```

I set my zoom size using the following property:

```
    "window.zoomLevel": -0.4  ,
```